# $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$, $f^n(x) = x^n$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, contest-math

I have been wondering, could there be any function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, such that $f^n(x) = x^n$. I have tried to make it easier by restricting it to $(0, \infty)$, but I couldn't find it...What do you think?

A variation of this problem was given to 10th grade students at a regional contest in Romania.

Comment: Does $f^{[n]}$ mean $f\circ\dots\circ f$ $n$-times?

Comment: Yes, it does. I should have added that.

Comment: For some $n$?  A fixed $n$?  All $n$?

Comment: Well, I was wondering more about cases where n is bigger, so let's pretend $n \ge 2$

Comment: @Randall Every $n \ge 2$

Comment: According to @marty's answer... Is $f$ the SAME for all $n$?

Answer (score 0):

Fix $n\ge 2$.

$f^{[2n]}(x)=x^{2n}$

$f^{[2n]}(x)=f^{[2n-1]}(f(x))=f(x)^{2n-1}$.

So $f(x)=x^{\frac{2n}{2n-1}}$. Since the expression of $f(x)$ depends on $n$, such $f$ cannot exists.

Comment: This looks very plausible, but there is a small problem. The problem given at that contest states the opposite...

Comment: What isEXACTLY the VARIATION of the problem you address in the question?

Comment: Well, it is not really a variation. They use this fact in their proof and it stunned me.

Comment: I've just proof that there cannot be a function $f$ such that ·$f^{[n]}=x^n$ for all $n\ge 3$. I think my proof is correct.

Comment: So do I, but then their proof falls. Maybe a function defined on $(0, \infty)$ could work?

Comment: @andueu Nothing in the proof in the answer relies on what values are in the domain. The function can't exist on any subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose this holds
for a particular value of $n$
(not all $n$).

Let's try
$f(x) = x^a$.
Then
$f^{[2]}(x)
=f(f(x))
=(x^a)^a = x^{a^2}
$,
$f^{[3]}(x)
=f^{[2]}(f(x))
=(x^a)^{a^2} 
= x^{a^3}
$,
and,
in general,
$f^{[n]}(x)
= x^{a^n}
$.

Therefore
$n = a^n$
so
$a = n^{1/n}
$.

If we compose the other way
so that
$f^{[n+1]}(x)
=f(f^{[n]}(x))
$
then,
assuming that
$f(x) = x^a$,
$f^{[2]}(x)
=f(f^{[1]}(x))
=(x^a)^a
=x^{a^2}
$,
$f^{[3]}(x)
=f(f^{[2]}(x))
=(x^{a^2})^a
=x^{a^3}
$,
and we get
the same result as before.

Comment: This solves the next problem: "For every $n\in\Bbb N$ there exists $f_n:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ such that $(f_n)^{[n]}=x^n$".

The OP should say what is the correct problem.

Comment: @TitoEliatron f should be the same for all n.